# How do I separate a row with delimited values into individual rows?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I have multiple columns with delimited data that need to be split into new rows. Some columns have single values that would need to be copied to the new rows. I can only see examples on the web of a single column with delimited data, so not sure how to apply solutions to multiple columns containing delimited data.

I need to create individual rows per delimited item where multiple columns contain delimited lists

What I have:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example on how you could approach this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim MyArray1() As String, MyArray2() As String
Dim X As Long, Y As Long, Z As Long

Z = 7
For X = 2 To 4
    MyArray1() = Split(Replace(Cells(X, 2).Value, " ", ""), ",")
    MyArray2() = Split(Replace(Cells(X, 3).Value, " ", ""), ",")
    For Y = LBound(MyArray1) To UBound(MyArray1)
        Cells(Z, 1).Value = Cells(X, 1).Value
        Cells(Z, 2).Value = MyArray1(Y)
        Cells(Z, 3).Value = MyArray2(Y)
        Cells(Z, 4).Value = Cells(X, 4).Value
        Z = Z + 1
    Next Y
Next X

End Sub
```

Output below

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to insert rows into the current table, as opposed to creating a new table below. The reason is, it could exceed the row limit per sheet. If not, can the output table be added to a new sheet?

Comment: Ofcourse it can! Just play around with where you want your output to be. Adding sheet references for example will be a quick solution to get your data on another sheet.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks again and for such a swift solution.

Comment: If a cell in one of the delimited fields is empty, the row is skipped in the output. Can you recommend code to cater for empty arrays?