# How to seperate multiple columns with delimited data into multiple rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset in which some columns have multiple values that are separated with ";" and some columns only have single values. I am trying to kinda split these into multiple rows, while preserving the ones that have single values.
I have already tried to use separate_rows in a loop fashion:

cols <- colnames(df)
for(col in cols) {
print(col)
df <- separate_rows_(df, col,sep = ";")
df <- df %>%  mutate(across(where(is.character), str_trim))
df <- unique(df)
gc()
}

However, this somehow gives me wrong combinations of values.
What I am trying to achieve is actually this:

[image: Turning this:]

[image: Into this:]

Comparable post but with excel:
[How do I separate a row with delimited values into individual rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572420/how-do-i-separate-a-row-with-delimited-values-into-individual-rows)

Thanks

Comment: This does not give me the result wanted, as I can only do this for one column at a time. If implemented in a loop, then it returns me combinatinations that doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @Eddytheturle, please revise the question, by including some dummy data that can be copied instead of posting pictures.

Comment: use `tidyr::separate_rows()` as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67870802/2884859) thread.

Comment: Ok i will do so